# Chained reference in Perl

Tags: perl

How to understand the following two lines of Perl codes:

```
%{$self->{in1}->{sv1}} = %{$cs->{out}->{grade}};
```

and

```
@{$self->{in1}->{sv1value}} = @{$cs->{out}->{forcast}};
```

Both of them involve using hashes and hash reference in a chain manner, except the first one uses % and the second one is an array object using @.  What are the resulting differences here, about which I am not very clear.

Comment: please consider updating the question title.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the first one `$self->{in1}->{sv1}` and `$cs->{out}->{grade}` are both references to hashes. So the line:

```
%{$self->{in1}->{sv1}} = %{$cs->{out}->{grade}};
```

Is replacing the contents of the has refrenced by `$self->{in1}->{sv1}` with the contents of the hash referenced by `$cs->{out}->{grade}`.

NOTE: This is very different to:

```
$self->{in1}->{sv1} = $cs->{out}->{grade}
```

Which just makes them reference the same hash.

The second line is doing the same thing except it is arrays which are referenced, not hashes.

Answer (score 2):

You answered your own question.  The first line copies a hash to a hash and the second line copies an array to an array!!  In other words `$self->{in1}->{sv1}` is a reference to a hash and `$self->{in1}->{sv1value}` is a reference to an array.